# Why can't I puppet a City-State in Civ V?

Tags: civilization-5, civilization-5-gods-and-kings

I started a game of Civilisation V with God & Kings expansion (GOTY edition, so a bunch of DLC as well). Started as Genghis Khan and warred a bit for prospective expansion areas, gaining an enemy capital, that I happily annexed. Then I turned my eye towards neighbouring city-states aiming to claim their luxury resources by conquering and puppeting them, but to no avail. Game didn't prompt me for choice, as I entered the city with my infantry, it immediately became annexed. Now I cannot raze or puppet the captured city-state. Why? Is this a game bug?

Comment: Is your civ in revolt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not a game bug. The game does not allow you to puppet an enemy capital once you capture it. Since a City State has only one city, that city is considered as their capital. Hence you cannot puppet a city state, in most cases.

Comment: What? I thought it was razing that was prevented. I could've sworn you still had the choice to annex or puppet city states and capitals.

Comment: If a city state has captured another city except their capital, and you conquer that city, then you have the option to puppet that city. If you conquer the city state's capital (their starting city) you don't get that option.